# Fluent NHibernate: foreign key field not being set in unidirectional association

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, associations

I have a database with a ProbateCases table and a Properties table. The Properties table has a foreign key to the ProbateCases table called ProbateCaseId, so the relationship between ProbateCases and Properties is one-to-many.

My domain layer has a ProbateCase class and a Property class. The ProbateCase class has a collection of Properties defined as follows:

```
private IList<Property> _properties = new List<Property>();
public virtual IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get { return _properties; } }
public virtual Property AddProperty()
    {
      Property property = new Property();
      _properties.Add(property);
      return property;
    }
```

The corresponding part of the Fluent NHibernate mapping looks like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.Properties).Where("Deleted = 0").KeyColumn("ProbateCaseId").Cascade.All().Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

Note that the association is unidirectional - the ProbateCase class has a collection of Properties, but the Property class does not have a ProbateCase member.

I'm finding that querying works fine - NHibernate is creating the appropriate SQL to get Properties with the appropriate ProbateCaseId value.

However, when I save a ProbateCase to which I have added a new Property, the INSERT SQL does NOT contain a value for the foreign key field - so I get a SQL Exception complaining of a NULL value in the foreign key:

```
INSERT INTO AdminOverview.Properties (PropertyName) VALUES ('Name of property') -- Where the hell is the ProbateCaseId field value???
```

Should I be expecting NHibernate to populate the foreign key value itself, or is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany:

> Very Important Note: If the  column of a  association is declared NOT NULL, NHibernate may cause constraint violations when it creates or updates the association. To prevent this problem, you must use a bidirectional association with the many valued end (the set or bag) marked as inverse="true". See the discussion of bidirectional associations later in this chapter.

Comment: Thanks Diego. I saw this before but it didn't really make sense to me. It's not a question of whether the FK field is nullable. I need the field to be set by NHibernate and it isn't being. I don't know why. Anyway, I have already fixed it (as indicated) by making the association bidirectional, but it's a hack because it doesn't really make sense semantically to be able to access the ProbateCase from the Property.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, *everyone* thinks this should work without making it bidirectional (and I understand it has worked in Java Hibernate for a while). It's just a limitation of the current implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For the benefit of other readers, you can do unidirectional associations in NHibernate, but only in ONE of the two possible ways. You must do the 'Class A has one Class B' association, not the 'Class B has many Class As' association.